# Why I can't reach the properties at Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm using a service to get data from backend.
The Controller is working fine.
And I can show the received object at the Angular GUI.

```html
<p> {{feedback | json}} </p>
```

The output looks like this:

*{ "id": 1, "comment": "Erster Eintrag, interessant.", "userId": 1012, "subject": "Mein Eintrag", "up": 22, "down": 2 }*

But when I try to access a single property of this received object:

```html
<p>Id: {{feedback.id}}</p>
```

Than I get a error:
[image]

**What I need to change to access all the properties and to show them at the GUI?**

My code snippets:

```js
export class CommentListComponent implements OnInit {

  feedbackIdAsString: string = '';
  feedbackId = 0;
  feedback: Feedback | undefined ;
  feedbacks: Feedback[] = [];
  comment_list: Comment[] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private feedbackService: FeedbackService,
    private commentListService: CommentListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.feedbackIdAsString = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('feedbackId') ?? '';
    this.feedbackId = +this.feedbackIdAsString;    this.feedbackService
      .getFeedback(this.feedbackId)
      .subscribe(feedback => this.feedback = feedback);

    this.feedbackService
      .getFeedbacks()
      .subscribe(feedbacks => this.feedbacks = feedbacks);

    this.commentListService
      .getComments()
      .subscribe(commentlist => this.comment_list = commentlist);
  }
}
```

```js
export class FeedbackService {

  public myUrl: string = "https://localhost:7235/feedback";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFeedbacks(): Observable<Feedback[]> {
    let result: Observable<Feedback[]>;
    result = this.http.get<Feedback[]>(this.myUrl);
    return result;
  }

  getFeedback(id: number): Observable<Feedback> {
    let result: Observable<Feedback>;
    let urlSingleFeedback = this.myUrl + '/' + id;
    result = this.http.get<Feedback>(urlSingleFeedback);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you're not dealing with the case where it's undefined.

Comment: I would make sure all the files are saved first, then if the error persists, check what variables you are using inside the template file and make sure there is no typo in the variable name. If that doesn't fix it, make sure all the variables used in the template are `public` (or at least not marked as `private` in the `.ts` file).

Comment: @jonrsharpe It looks like a compilation error. The `undefined` stuff is a runtime error and it will not happen at build time... right?

Comment: Or, the error message could hide something like "Property `id` does not exist on type `Feedback | undefined`?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu it's the compiler that's complaining _at build time_ so that you avoid hitting the error _at run time_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `feedback` is still undefined when rendering the template, because the `getFeedbacks` is most likely async. You can either put an `ngIf` or use `.?`

```
<p>Id: {{feedback?.id}}</p>
```

```
<p *ngIf="feedback?.id">Id: {{feedback.id}}</p>
```